# Windows8 Client cant download attachment

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I’m using the Windows 8 client and I can’t download an attachment.
When I try I get a message box saying “Downloading (NaN%)”

This works fine from an android device attached to the same server.

Any suggestions as to what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to install the Microsoft.WinJS.2.0 (framework).
Once this was installed it worked fine.

I wasn't installing these using the IBMApplicationCenter so this wasn't pulled in automatically.
The Microsoft.WinJS.2.0 (framework) is available in the IBMApplicationCenter as a separate installable item too.